# How do I connect my Bose QC35 with my MacBook Pro under iOS?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, headphones

My MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018 - OS Version 10.14.1 (18B75)) doesn't connect to my new Bose QC35. On the other hand, it connects without issues to my Pixel 3 XL.

I first connected without issues to my Pixel 3 XL named it Carol and then clicked on pairing other devices. Bose QC35/Carol didn't show up in the device list on the MacBook Pro.

To fix this I reset the device list on the Bose by longpressing on the bluetooth connection button and disabled Bluetooth on the Pixel while I did it. Unfortunately, that didn't help either.

When I boot Windows 10 on the MacBook Windows 10 has no problem connecting with the Bose QC35.

How do I get my Bose QC35 properly connected via Bluetooth with the MacBook Pro under iOS?

Comment: Does your Mac pair with other BT devices (i.e. phone, keyboard, mouse, etc.)?  Verify that BT is working on your MBP.  If it is, make sure your QC35 is in "pairing mode" and that it's broadcasting.

Comment: My MacBook is actively connected to a MX Ergo. Putting the QC35 into the pairing mode doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Do you hear the "Ready to connect" message? Have you tried resetting the macOS Bluetooth module? (Hold Shift-Option while clicking on the BT menu bar item > Debug menu > Reset the Bluetooth module)

Comment: @Gummibando Resetting the bluetooth module helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Gummibando's suggestion in the comments I resetted the bluetooth module on the MacBook Pro via:

> Hold Shift-Option while clicking on the BT menu bar item > Debug menu > Reset the Bluetooth module

This solved it for me.